# Passing and updating UI and data between component classes dynamically (React Native)

Tags: react-native

**My Goal:** In my app, I have a picker component wrapped in a *TxtMsgTypePicker* class. And I have another class called *TxtMsgParamView* which needs to receive the selected value from the TxtMsgTypePicker class and *as soon as* a value is selected by the TxtMsgTypePicker class, update the UI and data in my TxtMsgParamView class.

Here is my code:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        text: '',
        pickedTxtMsgType: enums.TxtMsgType.CONFIRM_PHONE_NUMBER

    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.parentView}>
        <View style={styles.view3}>
            <TxtMsgParamView
                onChangeText = {(text) => this.setState({text: text})}
                txtMsgType = {this.state.pickedTxtMsgType}
            >   
            </TxtMsgParamView>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.view4}>
            <TxtMsgTypePicker
                onValueChange = {(pickedTxtMsgType) => this.onPickedTxtMsgType(pickedTxtMsgType)}
            >
            </TxtMsgTypePicker>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Currently, I am able to send the selected value from the TxtMsgTypePicker class through props to the TxtMsgParamView class. However, the problem isn't getting the value from the TxtMsgTypePicker class the problem is, how does TxtMsgParamView class listen for the when it recieves the selected value from the TxtMsgTypePicker class so that *as soon as* the value is selected, the TxtMsgParamView class can do stuff with it such as update it's data and UI?

Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The main question is `the problem is, how does TxtMsgParamView class listen for the when it recieves the selected value from the TxtMsgTypePicker`, so the answer is: when you put the props to your child React components they update respectively on props change. If it's props did not change then the child component will not update.

You have to read the official docs [how React updates components](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#react-only-updates-whats-necessary) and I guess you want to make [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) in your `TxtMsgParamView`, so, please, read the article.